# How to highlight section in VScode live server when clicking my source code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, brackets

## Question

The editor **brackets** can do that. Supposed that, when I click my html tag in my source code file, the browser would automatically **highlight the section/div** in the broswer like google **chrome developer tools**.

## Step 1

Click my tag in my source code file

[image: enter image description hdere]

## Step 2

the live server will automatically focus on the section I want

[image]

## How could I make it in VSCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS Code does not have a built-in live server. Whatever extension you are using for live server can implement this, however I am not aware of any ones that do currently. Consider filing a feature request against them for this

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Five Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yandeu.five-server) extension.

I used to love this Live Preview of Brackets, mainly for two unique features unlike many other editors and extensions:

1. It shows the preview live, literally. It doesn’t wait for file save to show the changes.
2. Highlights the section in the preview, corresponding to the html tag in which the cursor is placed currently.